# Dividing 2 Multi-Index Data frames while retaining structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 MultiIndex data frames

The first looks like this:

```
v                         40                ...           200                      
                 p1       p2         p3     ...      p2        p3       p4
dates                                       ...                                
2019-12-01  0.031827  0.030943    0.027203  ...  0.014557    0.012797  0.010334
2019-12-02  0.027271  0.024006    0.022646  ...  0.011294    0.010654  0.010174
```

`.to_dict()` -->

```
A = 
{
  (43, 'p1'): 
     {
       '2019-12-01': 0.0318271824, 
       '2019-12-02': 0.0272707268, 
     }, 
  (43, 'p2'): 
     {
       ( ... )
      }, 
  (43, 'p3'): 
      {
        ( ... )
      }, 
  (210, 'p1'): 
      {
         ( ... ) 
       }
}
```

The 2nd of looks like this:

```
           section1                 section2  ... section3  section3                  
                p1   p2   p3   p4    p1     ...   p4      p1   p2   p3   p4
dates                                       ...                                 
2019-12-01  22.00  0.03  0.03  0.03  0.111  ...  0.03     0.03  0.03  0.03  0.03
2019-12-02   0.03  0.03  1.00  0.03  0.030  ...  0.03     0.03  0.03  0.03  0.03
```

`.to_dict()` -->

```
B = 
{
  ('section1', 'p1'): 
     {
       '2019-12-01': '22', 
       '2019-12-02': '0.03', 
     }, 
  ('section1', 'p2'): 
     {
       ( ... )  
     }, 
}
```

I would like to divide these 2 data frames together (A/B) and return the same structure as A. So like this:

```
v                         40                                     ...           200                      
                   p1               p2               p3                 ...      p2        p3       p4
dates                                                            ...                                
2019-12-01  0.031827 / 22.00   0.030943 / 0.03   0.027203 / 0.03  ...  0.014557    0.012797  0.010334
2019-12-02  0.027271  0.024006    0.022646       ...  0.011294    0.010654  0.010174
```

I am trying to handle the data as quickly as possible ...

** EDIT

to make it clearer I would like to create a dataframe that does divides A by B and keep the strcture of A... i.E:

```
 A = {
        (43, 'p1'): 
             {
               '2019-12-01': 0.0318271824
             }, 
        (210, 'p1'): 
              {
                 '2019-12-01': 0.0318271824
               }
   }

B = {
        ('section1', 'p1'): 
             {
               '2019-12-01': '22', 
             }, 
        ('section1', 'p2'): 
            {
                 '2019-12-01': '22'
            }, 
    }
```

```
C = {
        (43, 'p1'): 
             {
               '2019-12-01': 22 / 0.0318271824
             }, 
        (210, 'p1'): 
              {
                 '2019-12-01': 22 / 0.0318271824
               }
   }
```

Comment: For a multiindex, its always better to provide a code to reproduce the dataframe :)

Comment: The code is incredibly dense lol - will try to get something together

Comment: If they have the same number of columns, then `df1 / df2.set_axis(df1.columns, axis=1)` should do it... Right?

Comment: df A can have N number of top level indexes - will try your suggestion now :)  results in, `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 8 elements, new values have 28 elements`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly divide  on level = 1 after dropping the unnecessary multiindex column from B:

```
final1 = A.div(B.droplevel(0,1).astype(float),level=1)
```

---

```
                  43        210
                  p1        p1
2019-12-01  0.001447  0.001447
```

To get all elements in B even if it isnt present in A, you can `stack` the df A , then divide and unstack back with `swaplevel` and sort index for a multiindex view:

```
final2 = (A.stack(0).div(B.droplevel(0,1).astype(float),level=0).unstack()
                            .swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1))
```

---

```
                  43            210    
                  p1  p2        p1  p2
2019-12-01  0.001447 NaN  0.001447 NaN
```

Comment: I seem to get, `NotImplementedError: Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented` when trying this

Comment: Ahh yeah I had my dfs the wrong way round, looks like it works, however, the p1, p2... the index is present, but the 43, 210 index isn't there